# Limit of $\sqrt{4x+2} -2x$ as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

$\hspace{1cm} \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{4x+2}-2x\right) $

I have trouble finding answer to this one, I got stuck. Correct answer seems to be - infinity.

If I try to multiply the algebraic by a ... conjugate, I get:

$(\sqrt{4x+2}-2x) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{4x+2}+2x}{\sqrt{4x+2}+2x} = \frac{4x+2 -4x^2}{\sqrt{4x+2}+2x}  =  \frac {2(2x + 1 - 2x^2)}{\sqrt{4x+2} +2x}$

Dunno what to do next, any suggestions?

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205475/how-to-evaluate-this-limit-question-infinity/1205503#1205503

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the top and bottom by $\frac 1x$ to your very last expression. You will get $$\frac {2(2x + 1 - 2x^2)}{\sqrt{4x+2} +2x} \frac{\frac 1x}{\frac 1x}=\frac{2(2+\frac 1x - 2x)}{\sqrt{\frac 4x+\frac 2{x^2}}+2}$$
Now take the limit as $x \to \infty$. Your limit will be $-\infty$.

Comment: Uhm... if you multiply numerator by 1/x wouldn't you get 2/x(2+1/x - 2x) in the numerator ??? You seem to forgot to divide the first term by x too.

Comment: Without 2 in the front you get: 2 + 1/x -2x. I don't see how it answers the question. Shouldn't you multiply by 1/x every term in the numerator?

Comment: You do have the $2$ in the front this entire time. I'm saying this: $$2(2x+1-2x^2)\frac 1x=2\left(2x \cdot \frac 1x + 1 \cdot \frac 1x - 2x^2 \cdot \frac 1x\right)$$

Comment: @dramadeur $\frac{ab}c=a(\frac bc)=b(\frac ac)$

Comment: Couldn't you have done that multiplication as the first step as well?